# Data Structure for "Checking-Out" Resources?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is to the following problem.

I need to draw routes on a map. I have an ordered pool of colors I want to pick from. If the first color is available (not used yet) I want to use that color. If the first is used, I want to use the second color, and so on. In addition, the routes I draw can be grouped. So they may share the same color if the group is the same.

Here's an example:

Color List (Order matters): Blue, Red, Green, Yellow....

- First route is Group A. Blue is available: BLUE
- Second route is Group B. Blue is not available. Red is available: RED
- Third route is Group A. Group A is already using Blue so use that: BLUE
- The second route is removed
- Forth route is Group C. Blue is not available. Red is available: RED
- Fifth route is Group D. Blue and red are not available. Green is available: GREEN

I'm debating what the best data structure is for this type of system. I'll need to maintain the colors and their order, which groups have "checked-out" a color, and when I can "release" a color back into the pool of available choices.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

My current strategy is to use two data-structures. First would be a Dictionary where the key is the group name and the value is the color being used so I know who is currently using what color. The second structure would be a stack for maintaining the order of the colors that are available.

So when I want to add a new route, I first go to the dictionary to check if my group name exists. If it does, I'll use that assigned color. If it does not, I'll pull the next available color from the stack and then add my combination to the dictionary.

The ISSUE with this, is that it doesn't maintain a count of how many routes are in each group using a color. So let's say I have two routes in Group A using Blue. I remove a route. How do I know if there is another Group A route still using blue? I won't know if I can put blue back into the stack.

Comment: A stack let's me know what the next available color is, sure. But it doesn't help me to check if my route can use of the already "checked-out" colors if the groups match. And it doesn't help me to know if I can put a color back into the stack because I don't know if i'm the only route in the group using that color.

Comment: Regarding your edit - you didn't mention what data structure is used to maintain the group-route relationship.  Maybe another dictionary - key is group, value is hashset of routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine was similar.  I should probably clean it up more...

```
    class ColorAssigner
{
    public Dictionary<string, ColorGroupDetails> ColorAssignments { get; private set; }
    public SortedList<double, Color> Colors { get; private set; }

    public ColorAssigner()
    {
        ColorAssignments = new Dictionary<string, ColorGroupDetails>();
        Colors = new SortedList<double, Color>()  { { 1, Color.Blue}, {2, Color.Red}, {3,Color.Green}, {4,Color.Yellow} };
    }

    public Color RequestColor(string groupName)
    {
        if (ColorAssignments.ContainsKey(groupName)) 
        {
            ColorAssignments[groupName].Count++;
            return ColorAssignments[groupName].AssignedColor;
        }

        var assignedColor = GetNextAvailableColor();

        ColorAssignments.Add(groupName, new ColorGroupDetails() { Count = 1, AssignedColor = assignedColor });

        return assignedColor;
    }

    private Color GetNextAvailableColor()
    {
        var assignedColors = ColorAssignments.Select(a => a.Value.AssignedColor).ToList();

        return Colors.Values.Except(assignedColors).First();
    }

    public void ReleaseColor(string groupName)
    {
        if (ColorAssignments.ContainsKey(groupName))
        {
            var count = ColorAssignments[groupName].Count -= 1;

            if (count < 1) ColorAssignments.Remove(groupName);
        }
    }
}


    class ColorGroupDetails
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public Color AssignedColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to what I did. I appreciate the effort even though I figured this out on my own. Accepting since you put in the time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using a `Dictionary` and a `SortedList`

```
internal class ColorUseCounter
{
    public ColorUseCounter(int ColorID, Color Color)
    {
        this.ColorID = ColorID;
        this.Color = Color;
        Count++;
    }

    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

private static Dictionary<double, ColorUseCounter> UsedColors = new Dictionary<double, ColorUseCounter>();
private static SortedList<int, Color> AvailableColors = new SortedList<int, Color>()
{
    { 1, Color.FromArgb(74, 117, 175) },
    { 2, Color.FromArgb(226, 134, 48) },
    { 3, Color.FromArgb(94, 158, 64) },
    { 4, Color.FromArgb(185, 58, 46) },
    ...
    ...
};
```

The `Dictionary` is keyed on the GroupID which in my case is a double. So when I have a route to plot, I first check if my GroupID is in my `Dictionary`. If it is, I use that color for my route and I increase the `Count` by 1 so that I know how many routes are using that `Color`.

If my GroupID is NOT in the `Dictionary`, I go to my `SortedList` which uses the priority of the `Colors` as the key. So I grab the first item in the `SortedList` and add it to the `Dictionary` alongside my GroupID. Then I remove the `Color` from the `SortedList` since it is no longer available.

When I remove a route, I simply check the `Dictionary` to see if the `Count` has gone to zero. If so, I remove the `Dictionary` entry and reinsert the `Color` to the `SortedList`.

Work great.